Holding when no hold in-lieu of procedure turn present question

If I plan to do the ILS RWY 27 at Bainbridge, can I opt to hold at LYZ instead of doing the prescribed procedure turn? If so when can I descend from our en route altitude to 1900FT MSL to begin the approach?
My understanding is I can request holding and when holding complete start my descent on the inbound course. My only worry is if we have to lose a lot of altitude it could make for a difficult approach. What is the best course of action?

Note that the depicted hold at LYZ is for the missed approach procedure, not the "going toward the runway" approach procedure. I'm not actually sure if you'd be able to use it for course reversal or if you're required to fly the PT.

Is it me, or is it a bit strange that OLEEE is defined as 184° bearing to the station when it is nearly on top of the station?

@Timbo, nope, it's not just you.  Do NDBs have a much smaller cone of confusion such that you could ID the point if you were on centerline of the localizer?

@MichaelHall I would believe station passage would work (like at a compass locator) but this is defined by a bearing… bizarre!


Can I opt to hold at LYZ instead of doing the prescribed procedure turn?

You may request to hold in any manner you desire, and fly the hold however you are cleared to fly it.  Just be aware that for a non-standard request you may be questioned as to the reason, i.e. whether for troubleshooting a malfunction, etc.

If so when can I descend from our en route altitude to 1900FT MSL to begin the approach?

When you tell ATC you are ready to commence the approach and they clear you to descend.

What is the best course of action?

Fly the procedure turn as published, or request vectors to a straight-in ILS.  Why make more workload for yourself by inventing some new and unpublished procedure, especially one that puts you precariously high?
